# Why is this loop runs gradually slowly？

Tags: python, numpy

The flowing code is a simple python loop.

```
def getBestWeightsByRandomGradientAscent(featureDatasList, classTypes, maxCycles=1):
    """
    :param featureDatasList:
    :param classTypes:
    :param maxCycles: the loop time
    :return:
    """
    import random

    featureDatas = np.array(featureDatasList)
    m, n = np.shape(featureDatas)
    weights = np.ones(n)

    # the loop goes here... #
    for j in range(maxCycles):
        featureIndexs = range(m)
        featureLen = len(featureIndexs)
        for i in range(m):  
            delta = 4 / (1.0 + i + j) + 0.01
            randIndex = int(random.uniform(0, featureLen))
            sigmodInput = sum(featureDatas[randIndex] * weights)
            estimateClass = calculateSigmodEstimateClassType(sigmodInput)
            error = classTypes[randIndex] - estimateClass
            weights += (error * delta) * featureDatas[randIndex]
            del (featureIndexs[randIndex])

    return weights
```

I find that when I run this loop for 1000 or more times,it runs quickly at beginning,but it goes slower and slower as it runs,and finally keeps a slow speed...Curious,I don't why.Does it cause by the range of variables or my hardware problem? How can I fix this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you updating `weights` array correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `xrange` instead of `range`. It may be memory or the GC. You can profile your code with something like http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/runsnakerun/

Comment: Thanks! I will try that. ^_^